# htaccess 301 to dynamic URLs redirect to New dynamic URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to recirect my old dynamic  URLs to new dynamic URLs as follows :

http://example.com/test1/parent_record/requested_record
To 
http://example.com/test/detail/requested_record

Any suggestion how to do it?

Comment: Will `/test/detail/` be a static text before all new URLs?

Comment: yes /test/detail/ will be static

Answer (score 1):

You can use this generic `RedirectMatch` rule **as your very first rule**:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/test1/[^/]+/(.+)$ /test/detail/$1
```